# Disabling time row in DateBrowser.aspx in EPiServer

Tags: episerver

Here's the date browser I'm talking about:

[image]

I found these lines of code in `DateBrowser.aspx`:

```
var fNoTimeRow = <%# DisableTimeRow()  %>;
.
.
.
if (fNoTimeRow) 
{
    document.getElementById("timerow").style.display = "none";
}
```

But I can't seem to find where to toggle that property on/off anywhere in EPiServer. Where is this setting located?

Answer (score 0):

If the query string contains "notime=true", there will be no time in the selector